# rc.local not running program on boot

Tags: boot

I'm trying  to get the `/etc/rc.local` file to run my dotnet core app on startup. These commands work fine if I just manually type into the terminal.

I tried to setup logging on the `rc.local` to see whats happening but I can't find the file. Also I need to send as two separate commands, if I don't `cd` into directory first it doesn't work (manually anyway).

```
sleep 10

exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log      # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution

cd /home/pi/Desktop/Pisurvey
sudo dotnet pi-survey.dll

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked it out, I had an `iptables` command before it that was breaking it. What I didn't know beforehand is you can run the `rc.local` file manually in terminal and it will tell you if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `sudo` if you are auto running `/etc/rc.local` as it is run as root.

The file being run as root is probably causing the problem.

The root user has different default paths.  It is likely that `dotnet` is not in root's path.  Use the full path to `dotnet` within `/etc/rc.local`.